# Oracle SQL Group By where column is not in the group by or has an aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pandas-groupby

Suppose we have this:

| Category | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Truck | Engine | $300 |
| Truck | Lamp | $50 |
| Truck | Brake | $100 |
| Car | Engine | $400 |

How can we have a SQL statement that produces this? Assuming there is a one to one relationship between Item and Price, so that when we find the cheapest price we also display the item.

SELECT Category, Item, min(Price)

From table

group by Category

---

Can this be done without a subquery?

Can it be done in Python Pandas Group By?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The table you have shown is it source or expected output. If its expected output then include source table in your question. Besides the query example you have shown does not include a sub-query, what do you mean by done 'without' a subquery. Include example query of what you are referring to when you say subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> Assuming there is a one to one relationship between Item and Price

means ... what, exactly? That each item has only one price? That's "one-to-one", isn't it? If so, then what's the problem? Query you need is a simple

```
select category, item, price
from parts;
```

On the other hand, you wouldn't be saying

> so that when we find **the cheapest price** we also display the item

Cheapest price? So, one item can have multiple prices, after all? That's not one-on-one, then.

Anyway: presuming your table looks like this:

```
SQL> select category, item, price from parts order by 1, 2;

CATEG ITEM        PRICE
----- ------ ----------
Car   Engine        400
Truck Brake         100
Truck Engine        300         --> two prices for truck's engines
Truck Engine        999         --> (300 being the cheapest)
Truck Lamp           50
```

Query you wrote seems to be close to what you need - just include `item` into the `group by` clause:

```
SQL> select category, item, min(price) price
  2  from parts
  3  group by category, item
  4  order by category, item;

CATEG ITEM        PRICE
----- ------ ----------
Car   Engine        400
Truck Brake         100
Truck Engine        300
Truck Lamp           50
```

---

> Can this be done without a subquery?

Why? Not all subqueries are *evil*; the point is not to fetch data from the same table multiple times. Something like this doesn't - only the subquery (in a form of a CTE in this example) fetches data from the `parts` table; main query (line #6) just fetches rows with lowest price per category and item:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select category, item, price,
  3       rank() over (partition by category, item order by price) rn
  4     from parts
  5    )
  6  select category, item, price
  7  from temp
  8  where rn = 1
  9  order by category, item;

CATEG ITEM        PRICE
----- ------ ----------
Car   Engine        400
Truck Brake         100
Truck Engine        300
Truck Lamp           50

SQL>
```

---

> Can it be done in Python Pandas Group By?

I have no idea.

---

If that's not what you're looking for, you'll have to explain it better.